# How can I retrieve a record from my db using ajax and jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve records from my db using a button without the page refreshing. I'm not familiar with ajax and i've been having a hard time getting it to work. Here's what I have so far. any help would be appreciated, thank you

```
<h3>Avaiable assignments</h3><br>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#button1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getItem.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.success) {
            $("#responsecontainer").html(msg);
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
    });
  });
});
```

```
<br>
 <input name="button1" type="submit" id="button1" 
value="Picked" />
```

my getItem.php

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$q = intval($_GET['q']);


if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"items");
$sql="SELECT * FROM items WHERE LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['items'];
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`? Check for errors here.

Comment: i'm trying to retrieve them 1 at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to start in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools. There, **you can see the outgoing request and what it comes back with**.

Bring up your form in the browser and fire off the click event. Then, **find the request to 'getItem.php' and look at its response**. If it's not what you expect, set getItem.php to echo 'hello' and die; if the network tab does not show 'hello' in the response, that means you're not hitting the endpoint. If you see 'hello', congratulations, you're close!

In terms of your actual endpoint, I see you are repeatedly echoing the results of your query. This is not the most useful way to do this. Instead, **json_encode the entire results set, echo that, and kill the script**. This will return all your table rows as a JSON array which can then be **read by javascript back on the client side.**. I hope any of this helps!

Comment: thanks i got the data showing in my network tab so i know the query is running successfully now, however i can't get the data to echo out onto the page

Comment: What does the data look like coming back from the endpoint? (Copy/paste from the console is fine)

Comment: i tried doing something like: $myJSON = json_encode($result);

echo $result;    - but it keeps returning an error (Catchable fatal error)

Comment: instead of storing it in a variable, simply use: echo json_encode($result); die();

Comment: i did that, now getting this: {"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}.

Comment: That means either your query isn't functioning properly, or that you need to loop through the results set ($result) differently – I am not very familiar with mysqli methods but maybe go back and try that while loop again